# How to set up a multi-developer Biztalk environment?

Tags: development-environment, biztalk

If we have 3 developers working on the same Biztalk project what is the best way to set up our development environment?

We are using TFS to store the Biztalk project.

Should we use 1 sql server and 1 Biztalk server and then have 1 or more developer machines that access the sql and biztalk servers?  The issue we get with this is when 1 developer compiles and deploys their changes it can effect other developers if they are also trying to compile and deploy their work.

Should we have each developer host their own complete sql and biztalk server for local development either on their machine or within their own virtual machine?  The problem we find with this is that each developer could modify their server settings and those settings are not stored in source control.  This can cause confusion when changes are deployed to a testing server.  Another smaller issue is that each developer would need to have sql server, biztalk server and windows server installed.

Is there another way to set up a multiple developer biztalk development environment?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will *always* want to have each developer have a complete BizTalk installation on their own machines. Believe me, it doesn't work otherwise, as you'll just keep getting on each other while trying to deploy/test/debug changes.

That said, you will also want a centralized dev/test environment where you deploy your code for more complete integrated testing and making sure all the changes from everyone are seen together.

Your point about configuration is true, but only up to a point. This is because you should make your solution configuration *part* of your source code and keep it in source control as well. This is particularly important once you're a bit ahead in your development as you'll need to start maintaining multiple versions of your binding files for each environment (dev, test, production and so on).

Comment: Thank you.  I think I agree.  Also thank you for reminding me about binding files.  I'm not too experienced with BizTalk and forgot about that.

Answer (score 2):

tomasr is right. Also, if you have decent hardware and lots of RAM, you may want to setup a VM image of your full developer environment, then share this will all your team. Not as fast as native hardware, but does allow you to roll back changes, replace your VM if you really mess up and everyone then has the same environment – ideally close to the target one.
Setting up a continuous build server is also a most, if your projects are small, you can get each checkin to cause a full build, BizTalk deploy, export of MSI and then run tests. Later as your solutions get more numerous you might have to move to a continuous build of C# changes only, then say nightly or several times a day, you do a full. We have done this with CruiseControl.net, Nant, nunit and various power shell scripts, it was pretty time consuming, but each morning we come to work to find a fully compiled, deployed, exported and tested set of BizTalk solutions ready for the test team.